# put some key text from prefences.xml

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have a save some data from my preferences.xml
but i want to  put url  to my activitity.java

here my code
;`public static final String PREFS_NAME = "mypreferemce.xml";`

and this is my url to get some key from preference.xml

```
 public void lampu1(View view) {
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {

        final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview5);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                wv.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/1.html");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "koneksi error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        wv.canGoBack();
       wv.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");


    }
```

and this is my preference.xml

```
<string name="mypreference_string">http://someurl.com</string>
```

thanks for help

Comment: Your question is unclear. mypreference_string is a string variable not a shared preference what do you want to do exactly.

Comment: just replace someurl from activity with someurl on preference.xml

Comment: You are saving data in sharedpreference using xml?

Comment: yups,any idea,or this is wrong way to do that

Comment: SharedPreference via xml give you three types only EditTextPreference, CheckboxPreference and ListViewPReference. You need to handle this thing via code. I am posting code below add it and let me know if any help is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code make a class like this and wherever you need to use to save any thing in **shared preference** use its **set** method and to retrieve any value from **SharedPreference** use its **get** method.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class SharedPrefManager {

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPref(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return pref;
    }

    public static void setPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, String value) {
        if(key!=null){
        Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
        edit.putString(key, value);
        edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setIntPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, int value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putInt(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setLongPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, Long value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putLong(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setBooleanPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, boolean value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putBoolean(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }


    public static String getPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        String val = "";
        try {
            if (pref.contains(key))
                val = pref.getString(key, "");
            else
                val = "";
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static int getIntPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        int val = 0;
        try {
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getInt(key, 0);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static Long getLongPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        Long val = null;
        try{
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getLong(key, 0);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return val;
    }

    public static boolean getBooleanPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        boolean val = false;
        try{
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getBoolean(key, false);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }


    public static boolean containkey(Context mContext,String key)
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        return pref.contains(key);
    }   

}
```

Try it if any help is needed to implement this then let me know.

Comment: okay, this is so help,now i need code  to replace some url to string from shared pref   wv.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");

Comment: did not get your question @AhmadYusuf plz explain it wat you want to ask ?

Comment: Set your url like this :
SharedPrefManager.setPrefVal(this, "url", "someurl.com");
you need to write something like this : wv.loadUrl(SharedPrefManager.getPrefVal(this, "url"));