# Can we Call two different shared preferences data inside one method in java?

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
SharedPreferences preferences_type = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String preferences_typename = preferences_type.getString("name", sname);
String preferences_typeSocietyname = preferences_type.getString("societyname", ssociety);
String preferences_typeFlatno = preferences_type.getString("Flatnumber", sflat);
//Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"name"+preferences_typeS,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
name.setText(preferences_typename);
society.setText(preferences_typeSocietyname);
Flatno.setText(preferences_typeFlatno);

SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String previouslyEncodedImage = shre.getString("image_data", "");

    if( !previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
        byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //profileImage.setImageResource(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, profileImage);
    }
```

Comment: yes you can Are you getting any issue ?

Comment: You can call, but what is that you are trying to solve, what is your need. ?

Comment: I want to fetch data from SharedPreferences. One is coming from Activity one and another from another frm Activity two , now call them separtly in another common activity

Comment: @PreetikaKaur can u plz tell how to call them in singl activity.

Comment: Is your SharedPrefrence file is same or different ?

Comment: Different, I want to fetch profile image in Nav Header Side Bar, So while Signup i have kept the image in Shared Preference, And Calling it on Nav Header method. Following same for User Name also with Different Shared Preference key in different Activity, So doubt is this if i can call two shared data in common activity wih diffent data.?

Comment: I dont think for this you need different shared preferences files. It ll be handled with jst one sharedpref file

Comment: The data are in two different Activity , il be needing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803521/put-some-key-text-from-prefences-xml/39803633#39803633 Use this link It ll help you and let me know if any help is required.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i change User Profile image in nav header according to current user in parse ?

Comment: keep one variable for user image ok and then save it in sharedpreference using the class mentioned in above link and then replace the value using set and get functions from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just use preference name to uniquely address them.

```
//create shared preference 1 where you want
SharedPreferences data1 = this.getSharedPreferences("pref1", 0);
   //put some data
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data1.edit();
   editor.putString("string1", "some string");
   editor.commit();

//create shared preference 2 where you want
SharedPreferences data2 = this.getSharedPreferences("pref2", 0);
   //put some another data
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data2.edit();
   editor.putString("string2", "some another string");
   editor.commit();
```

You can retrieve that data where ever you want uniquely by refering the name you gave when creating the SharedPreference.

```
SharedPreferences somedata1 = this.getSharedPreferences("pref1", 0);
    String someStr1 = somedata1.getString("string1", "default");
    // use data

SharedPreferences somedata2 = this.getSharedPreferences("pref2", 0);
    String someStr1 = somedata1.getString("string2", "default");
    // use data
```

hope this helps.